# Recursive G(n) function error

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I have a function to work out g(n) where g(n)=f(n,n) and can be recursively defined as

f(i, j) = 1
3
(f(i − 1, j) + f(i − 1, j − 1) + f(i, j − 1)),

f(0, 0) = 0; f(i, 0) = 1, i > 0; f(0, j) = 1, j > 0.

```
static final Map<List<Double>, Double> CACHE = new HashMap<>();

private static double f(double i, double j) {
    if (i == 0.0 && j == 0.0) return 0.0;
    if (i == 0.0 || j == 0.0) return 1.0;
    List<Double> key = Arrays.asList(i, j);
    Double a = CACHE.get(key);
    if (a != null)
        return a;
    double result =  (1.0 / 3) * (f(i - 1, j) + f(i - 1, j - 1) + f(i, j - 1));

    CACHE.put(key, result);
    return result;
}

private static double g(double n) {

    return f(n, n);

}



}
```

Im trying to calculate values of n=10^1,10^2,10^3,10^4,10^5,10^6. The first 3 results are calculated fine but then for the next the program crashes with :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.util.HashMap$TreeNode.getTreeNode(HashMap.java:1873)
at java.util.HashMap.getNode(HashMap.java:575)
at java.util.HashMap.get(HashMap.java:556)
at javaapplication7.Question3.f(Question3.java:72)
```

Can anyone see a way to fix this? Also what would the storage and run time complexities be ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is just as the name of the exception : `StackOverflowError`. For case n = 10000, so we need to call function `f` 10000*10000 times, and all of the function calls are kept in the Stack memory, which causes stack overflow.

- So, one option is you can increase the Java stack size.
- Or, you can consider change from recursive approach to iterative approach.

Observation: to calculate a state `f(i, j)`, we only need to know state `f(i - 1, j), f(i - 1, j - 1)` and state `f(i, j - 1)`, which only require two arrays, one holds the result for the current `i`, one holds result for `i - 1`. So we can come up with an iterative solution like this, which only requires O(2*n) space :

```
int[] lastResult = new int[n + 1];

for(int i = 1; i < n; i++){
    int[] f = new int[n + 1];
    for(int j = 1; j <= n; j++){
        f[j] = lastResult[j] + lastResult[j - 1] + f[j - 1];
    }
    lastResult = f;
}
```

Comment: Or, alternative 3: Add a case that breaks out of the recursive call.  Basically, a recursive call needs a LIMIT.  The code above is boundless.

Comment: what would the run time and storage complexity be of my current solution?

Comment: @david223 your run time is O(n^2), and space is also O(n^2)